# jogl installation to native library

Tags: jogl

How can we add jogl to native java library so that we can run a jogl program like any other java program using notepad without any ide like netbeans, eclipse.
I have downloaded jogl. To test it i have run the following example program given in the documentation.

But i get an error saying the package javax.media.opengl doesnot exist.
i read the installation guide in tutorialspoint.But it is given for an ide.
can't we run the jogl program using notepad.

```
import javax.media.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;                                        
import javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilities;                                          
import javax.media.opengl.GLEventListener;                                        
import javax.media.opengl.GLProfile;                                              
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class BasicFrame implements GLEventListener                                
{
   @Override
   public void display(GLAutoDrawable arg0)                                         
   {                                                                            
      // method body                                                               
   }

   @Override
   public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable arg0)                                       
   {                                                                                       //method body                                                              
   }                                                                        
   @Override                                                                   
   public void init(GLAutoDrawable arg0)                                          
   {                                                                           
      // method body                                         
   }   

   @Override                                                                     
   public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {    
      // method body                                                              
   }  

   public static void main(String[] args)                                            
   {    
      //getting the capabilities object of GL2 profile                           
      final GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);                     
      GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(profile);                                                        
      // The canvas                                                              
      final GLCanvas glcanvas = new GLCanvas(capabilities);                        
      BasicFrame b = new BasicFrame();                                             
      glcanvas.addGLEventListener(b);                                                  
      glcanvas.setSize(400, 400);                                                                                 
      //creating frame                                                           
      final Frame frame = new Frame (" Basic Frame");                                                                             
      //adding canvas to frame                                                    
      frame.add(glcanvas);                                                       
      frame.setSize( 640, 480 );                                                
      frame.setVisible(true);                                                     
   }  
}
```

Comment: tutorialspoint isn't officially supported by the JogAmp community and may contain obsolete or inaccurate tutorials. "javax.media" has been replaced by some other packages: https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=682 Please look at our API documentation: http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/

Comment: thanks, link helped a lot, but i wanna know if we can run jogl program from notepad instead of an ide

Comment: You can use Notepad, emacs, vi, Notepad++ or any other text editor to write code and compile in command line: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE#vi_and_other_text_editors